# COCOA: Fill Popup button with Enum

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know it seems to be a silly question but I am facing problem in finding a way to fill `popup button` with an enum. Reson behind it is that it will be easier for me to do `switch case`.

Comment: Do you want to fill with Enum's string constant?

Comment: yes @AnoopVaidya, and want to do Switch Case on as well

Comment: Use the tag of the menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use `enum` to populate the `NSPopupButton` as items. There would be multiple issues with handling them.

First of all `enum` are not any object, in fact they are just a named `integer` constants, while `NSPopupButton` expects `NSString` to be its value/title.

Assuming if you manually feed the same name in `NSPopupButton`, then the `IBAction`'s sender will return the value back as `NSString`. Here again you need to manually compare with the integer values. Then you will run a switch case...huh. That is too ugly to do.

**EDIT**: The workaround.

Create an array of strings exactly same order as of enum, and make sure enum is continous starting from 0. Then on click of popup, compare the title of popup with the array and filter out the index, and that index will be same as your enum's!

**EDIT: Example**

```
enum  /// create an enum with all values
{
    sizeBytes = 1,
    sizeKb = 2,
    sizeMb,
    sizeGB
};

/// create an array and fill the enum values manually. Enum indexes should match array indexes
NSMutableArray* _sizeList = [NSMutableArray new];

[_sizeList addObject:@"BYTES"];
[_sizeList addObject:@"KB"];
[_sizeList addObject:@"MB"];
[_sizeList addObject:@"GB"];



  /// do switch case as gven below : **sizeSelector** is popup button
  switch ([sizeSelector indexOfSelectedItem]) {
        case sizeGB:
            //do the code
            break;
        case sizeMb:
            //do the code
            break;
            //......so on
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: is there any other approach that I can use to achieve the desired task(populating and do comparisons)?

Comment: @VikasBansal: Create an array of strings **exactly same order as of enum, and make sure enum is continous starting from 0**. Then on click of popup, compare the title of popup with the array and filter out the index, and that index will be same as your enum's!